# MySQL select query from multiple tables with phrase

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I have trouble figure out how to make the mysql statement to get the correct records.
What i want to do is:

1. find if the query-keyword is in keywords table and get the id
2. check connection table for keywordid and get all adid's
3. fetch all records from ads table that have the connection and is status 1

What also want to do is to match e.g "travel" to "travels", "travel to europe" et.c. (Like a phrase match)

Ads table:

| id | title | desc | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | title1 | desc1 | 1 |
| 1 | title2 | desc2 | 0 |
| 2 | title3 | desc3 | 1 |

keywords table:

| id | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | keyw1 |
| 1 | keyw2 |
| 2 | keyw3 |

connection table:

| id | keywid | adid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | keyid1 | 2 |
| 1 | keyid2 | 1 |
| 2 | keyid3 | 3 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're not familiar with JOIN in SQL you should study up on it. If you are familiar, please [edit] your question to show us what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information given the query needed is as follows.

> ```
> create table ads (
> id    int,
> title varchar(10),
> descr varchar(10),
> status    varchar(10));
> insert into ads values
> (0,   'title1',   'desc1',    1),
> (1,   'title2',   'desc2',    0),
> (2,   'title3',   'desc3',    1);
> create table keywords (
> id    int,
> keyword varchar(10));
> insert into keywords values
> (0,   'keyw1'),
> (1,   'keyw2'),
> (2,   'keyw3');
> create table connection (
> id    int,
> keywid    varchar(10),
> adid int);
> insert into connection values
> (0    ,'keyid1',  2),
> (1    ,'keyid2',  1),
> (2    ,'keyid3',  3);
> GO
> ```

9 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT a.*
> FROM keywords k
> JOIN connection c
> ON k.id = c.id
> JOIN ads a
> ON c.adid = a.id
> WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%keyw%'
> AND status = 1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title  | descr | status
> -: | :----- | :---- | :-----
>  2 | title3 | desc3 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b880c3ba64c25dfe1a77124f2f0a3c42)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but I get duplicate ads. How can i solve this?

Comment: You can either use DISTINCT with  the first line as  `SELECT  DISTINCT a.*` or use GROUP BY in which case you need to name the columns in the SELECT and then name them in a `GROUP BY column_1, column_2` after the WHERE conditions. DISTINCT is simpler, and at least as fast if not faster then GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

as per your requirement please try below Query

```
SELECT * FROM keywords AS t1
   INNER JOIN CONNECTION AS t2 ON (t1.id=t2.keywid)
   INNER JOIN Ads AS t3 ON (t2.adid=t3.id)
   WHERE t1.keyword like '%here your keyword%' AND t3.status=1;
```